# search a pattern and swap 1st value to second value after pattern match

Tags: regex, awk

Input

```
Tot1          := Getceiling(1,'0002125','DIS');
Tot2          :=  Getceiling(1,'0002125','TDIS') + Getceiling(1,'0002125','PDIS');
```

Output Getceiling and swap parameter pass in this function 1st and 2nd only

find

```
Tot1          := Getceiling('0002125',1,'DIS');
Tot2          :=  Getceiling(0002125,1,'TDIS') + Getceiling('0002125',1,'PDIS');
```

tried this to at least print the value

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i!="Getceiling"){print $2} } }' myfile
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: swap parameter pass in Getceiling function like 1,'0002125' should be '0002125',1

Comment: And you want that to happen in all the 3 calls of `Getceiling`?

Comment: Yes, in first line there is 1 occurrence and second line there is two occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/\(Getceiling(\)\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\1\3\2/g' input
```